# Usernames can overflow the box

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Just noticed this username overflowing the space reserved for it and ending up behind our Hot Meta Posts box over on [Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com).

[image]

I think this problem is rare, but there should be a way to wrap or otherwise neaten this.

Comment: Over on MSO there is a bug reported that the [Hot Meta Posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312035/what-happened-to-the-hot-meta-posts) are gone. If that bug can be pushed to Security.se the username is no longer behind the hot meta posts ....

Comment: I think, on balance, I'd like the hot meta posts box to stay... Thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue has been resolved by adding `word-wrap: break-word;` to the `user-details` div.

[image]