# Large badge counts produce a line break in the usercard

Tags: bug, design, user-card

Recently, this started happening:

> [image: image of the problem]

Shog9 has an immense amount of badges, so many that the number creates a linebreak in the usercard, resulting in weird space below the usercard of the post's author. It also happens when a well-decorated user is the post's author; then the box is just extra tall:

> [image: picture with just one usercard]

I first noticed it when looking at "[The new edit rejection message for "no improvement whatsoever" sounds too hostile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242159/295684)." The problem also appears on Stack Overflow:

> [image: Jon Skeet]

I'm using Google Chrome 47.0.2526.73 on Windows 8.1 at 1920x1080 at the default zoom level.

**Updated** 12/26/2015: This is not fixed. It was, momentarily, fixed on Meta Stack Exchange (but not for Jon Skeet's usercard on Stack Overflow), but now the problem is happening again, even at the page I linked above.

**After Winter Bash ended** (tested 1/5/2016): It's still happening, both here and [at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/2825369).

Related, maybe: [Usernames can overflow the box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270567/295684)
Related, definitely, but not a duplicate: [Is there enough space in the user card for users who have a very large number of badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156205/295684)

Comment: -1 for not using Jon Skeet as the example.

Comment: @Mysticial is totally right. You can't possibly leave Jon Skeet out of such a bug report. Fixed. :-D

Comment: This is a dupe of another similar, and equally pointless, question, but I care so little about the entire subject that I won't go looking for it.  Might be on meta.so....

Comment: The line wrap wouldn't be invasive if it didn't then push everything else on the page down.  I noticed this when looking at the users list on one of my sites; the uneven row-to-row spacing jumped out at me, and is new.  there's plenty of space between entries already, so it feels like even with the line wrap the user entry could be made to fit without affecting the overall layout.  (I know it's a first-world problem, but between a positional memory and knowing how many page-down operations get me through the page -- except when they don't -- it bugs me a little.)

Comment: This issue was brought up [on Stack Overflow Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312042/user-profile-badge-text-wrapping-issue). Can you provide links to the examples you took pictures of above so I can verify if the issue is still persisting?

Comment: @Hynes I took my screenshots from http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242159/295684, but I don't know where Shadow Wizard got the Jon Skeet one from.

Comment: @Ben from Stack Overflow, see the reputation. :)

Answer (score 4):

I've been playing around with this, and it won't work in the current design. If you want all badges to be on one line you need to change the width of `<div class="post-signature flex--item fl0">` from `200px` to `250px`.

There are currently 2 of these items next to each other under a post, one for the information of the post owner, and one for the user that edited that post last. If I make the change described above on a random post this is the result:

[image]

You can see that the post links on the left have been crammed together, and that there is loads of white space around the usercards now, as these users don't have the amount of badges in the range that Shog9 has them. For his postsignature this looks relatively fine now with the increased width.

[image]

And truncating the amount of badges he has doesn't make all that much of a difference:

[image]

The real solution would be to have the badge indicator and the badge count stick together, and wrap to the new line together, that would make it far less ugly. That is actually quite easy. You can simply add `white-space: nowrap;` to `.user-info .-flair`. Downside is that the badge count now runs out of bounds, as you can see in the screenshot below, but for now that's acceptable (I think)

[image]

And on a larger view it looks like this:

[image]

This is however also bound to cause problems when users get loads of badges and edit other users posts:

[image]