# Summarize badge counts > 1000

Tags: feature-request, design, badges

There exists (glorious) users on various StackExchange sites with more than 1000 badges. This makes the formatting of the user profile at the bottom of questions/answers a little odd, as the badge information overflows to the next line.

> [image: user with a large badge count]

Would it make sense to summarize badge counts larger than 1000 in a similar way to reputation? Using the above screenshot as an example, the users's badge count would instead be:

`* 109  * 1k  * 1k`

This is a nitpick and low priority, but maybe it would make a good on-boarding task for a new hire?

Comment: `1k` for the range from 1000 to 1999 wouldn’t be consistent with the way reputation is shortened.

Comment: @SebastianSimon you are correct and it turns out I don't actually know how reputation is abbreviated/shortened.

Comment: related bug report: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270588/large-badge-counts-produce-a-line-break-in-the-usercard